# knockout.js - data-bind auto update after function call

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I have a case where I databind to a date field inside model in a list:

```
function Model(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
}

<div id="fieldOnPage" data-bind="text: formatDate(myDateField())"></div>
```

Then, in a modal, I display the same date field so it can be edited:

```
<div id="fieldInModal" data-bind="text: formatDate(myDateField())"></div>
```

However, since I'm calling the formatDate function does its work on the unwrapped observable, I'm unable to see the changes get written real-time back onto the main page when I edit the value in the modal.

Another caveat is that I using the ko.mapping plugin so I don't necessarily have a specific ko.computed field on myDateField.  Is this possible to do with an external function like this? If not, how would I do it using the ko.computed if I had to specifically override the myDateField binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
function Model(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

    this.formattedDate = ko.computed(function () {
       return formatDate(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(self.myDateField));
    });
}
```

The bind to the formatted Date

```
<div id="fieldInModal" data-bind="text: formattedDate"></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey! Thanks again for another response.  This is a good start.  However, I want the field on the page to also update in sync with the bound field in the modal.  And, if possible.  I was noticing that the bound field on the page was not updating with this strategy.

Comment: The formattedDate computed will update whenever the Model.myDateField is updated. If I understand you correctly the Modal is binding to a copy of your underlying page field. You should maybe rethink how you structure your modal viewmodel to take references from the page viewmodel. Until I see more code it's hard to say. Can you update with a complete example showing the page and modal not working together.

Comment: Computed observables by default are not writable. Think about it, how could knockout reverse engineer the function used to create the value.  All you need to do to get @madcapnmckay's example to work is to make formattedDate a writable computed. Here's the documentation http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html . Scroll down to the writable computed section.

Comment: Here's a fiddle to demonstrate how you'd do it http://jsfiddle.net/bczengel/yyAHG/

Comment: This is 100% the answer I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: @AdamLevitt - Wow I totally misunderstood what you were after.

Comment: I'll add my solution to @madcapnmckay's and Adam can mark this question answered.